# django 3.0 inline admin form foreignkey -> foreignkey

Tags: django

I have any models and one Manager

app/models.py

```
class castratedListStudent(models.Manager):
    use_in_migrations = False
def get_query_set(self):
    return super().get_query_set().filter(isOn=1)

class student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isOn = models.BooleanField()

    default_manager = castratedListStudent()
    objects = castratedListStudent()

class discipline(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nameDiscipline = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    itemIdToDiscip = models.ForeignKey(item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class listOfStudForDiscipline(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    discipListId = models.ForeignKey(discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studId = models.ForeignKey(student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am using django inline

accounts/admin.py

```
class discipStudentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = listOfStudForDiscipline
    admin.TabularInline.verbose_name = 'Student'
    extra = 0

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(studId__isOn=1)

class disciplineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = discipline
    inlines = [discipStudentInline]
```

The Inline form is displayed on the HTML page and filter (studId__isOn=1) works. But the problem is that on the HTML page below there is a field that allows you to add another student and the list of students is not filtered by the filter rule(studId__isOn=1) When I check in the DEBUG_SQL console, I can see how the query goes without the WHERE expression "FROM journal_student".

```
(0.000) SELECT `journal_listofstudfordiscipline`.`id`, `journal_listofstudfordiscipline`.`discipListId_id`, `journal_listofstudfordiscipline`.`studId_id` FROM `journal_listofstudfordiscipline` INNER JOIN `journal_student` ON (`journal_listofstudfordiscipline`.`studId_id` = `journal_student`.`id`) WHERE (`journal_student`.`isOn` = 1 AND journal_listofstudfordiscipline`.`discipListId_id` = 1) ORDER BY `journal_student`.`lastName` DESC; args=(True, 1)
(0.000) SELECT `journal_student`.`id`,..., `journal_student`.`descriptionStudent` FROM  journal_student` ORDER BY `journal_student`.`lastName` ASC, `journal_student`.`firstName` ASC; args=()
```

I couldn't solve the problem using the model Manager.

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turned out that after django version 1.7, the get_query_set() method was renamed to get_queryset(). And the Manager will now look like this:

```
class castratedListStudent(models.Manager):
    use_in_migrations = False
def get_query_set(self):
    return super(liveListStudent, self).get_queryset().filter(isOn=1)
```